# ASP.NET Universal Providers and Session State

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database, universal-provider

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 website and I'm using the [Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers). I plan to deploy to Windows Azure and use SQL Database. In order to initialize memberships, profiles and roles on my local SQL Server 2008 database, I created a new user via the ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool. How do I initialize sessions?

When my application runs, naturally I get a SqlException saying "Invalid object name dbo.Sessions." When testing on Windows Azure, this wasn't an issue; dbo.Sessions was created automatically. I'm able to run locally after generating a create table script from dbo.Sessions on Azure and applying it to my local SQL database.

web.config:

```
<membership hashAlgorithmType="SHA1" defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile enabled="false" defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="false" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article goes into more detail of the differences between the old aspnet_Memembership vs the Universal Providers.

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/stronger-password-hashing-net

The key points from the article:

Firstly, there’s **no more aspnet_regsql**, you just make sure your connection string is set and the account has DBO rights (don’t worry, it doesn’t have to stay this way) then run the app up and attempt to **perform any action** which should cause the membership provider to hit the DB (i.e. log on – it doesn't matter that there isn't an account).

Thats it all there is to it, when it works.

Comment: There is one thing that nearly drove me crazy. I was toying with this, using Studio 2012 and IIS Express, and did something wrong in the configuration. I fixed it later, but the exception did not disappear. On a whim, I closed the running IIS Express instance - and then it worked. I assume that it stored a flag somewhere, saying that the tables should be there already.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers to deploy to Windows Azure & SQL Database, it seems there could be some issue with your connection string as table on SQL Database is not created.

The blog below from Soctt shows steps by step details on how to do it so please follow and see what is missing:

[Introducing System.Web.Providers - ASP.NET Universal Providers for Session, Membership, Roles and User Profile on SQL Compact and SQL Azure](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)