# Silverlight WCF Ria Services app built with Visual Studio 2012 fails while creating Users table for membership

Tags: wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-2012, membership, silverlight-5.0

I am creating a Silverlight 5 application with RIA Services under Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012. I added a model pointing to my database, created the domain service and everything works fine.
Now I need to add membership functionality and so I was thinking of using the good'old aspnet_regsql to add the new tables, views, sprocs, etc. needed by the ASP.NET subsystem.
I learned here http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/stronger-password-hashing-net that aspnet_regsql is no longer used and that a Universal Provider is now used.
However, my database already contained a table named Users and so after I tried to log in to the newly created app (as suggested here: [ASP.NET Universal Providers and Session State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105759/asp-net-universal-providers-and-session-state)), the other tables got created, but the Users table didn't (since it already existed).
Then when I try to run the app and create a new user, the app crashes on line 62 of the default UserRegistrationService.cs file that says:
Membership.CreateUser(user.UserName, password, user.Email, user.Question, user.Answer, true, null, out createStatus);
The inner exception of that error is:
Invalid column name 'ApplicationId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserName'.\r\nInvalid column name 'ApplicationId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'UserName'.\r\nInvalid column name 'IsAnonymous'.\r\nInvalid column name 'LastActivityDate'.

I think the problem is that the Users table didn't get created. But I don't know how to fix this problem.

Any suggestions?
Thanks to all!
Trex